# Getting Class is not a View Error When Using a Custom Class in Layout - Android TV

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tv

I am getting the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Class is not a View com.abcxyzradio.ActionsRow
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wholeView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.abcxyzradio.ActionsRow
        android:id="@+id/actions_row_actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
@Override
protected RowPresenter.ViewHolder createRowViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.now_playing_channel_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}
```

ActionsRow is extended from the Row class. What might be missing, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "the Row class" you mean [this `Row` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/Row.html), that is not a widget, despite being in a Java package with `widget` in the name. `Row` inherits from `Object`, not `View`, and so you cannot use it in layout.